# Remove white space around base plot

Tags: r, plot, bar-chart

I want to remove the empty/white space around the figure and save it as a png file. I really need help on this

Here is my code:

```
valores=c(12.5,25.0,12.5,25.0)
names(valores)=c("Escrita","Leitura","Comp. Oral","Exp. Oral")
par(mai=c(1,1.2,1,1))
barplot(valores,horiz = TRUE,xaxt="n",xlim=c(0,100),width=0.3,ylim=c(0,5),xlab=c("Nível"),space=c(0.3,0.3,0.3,0.3),
      col="firebrick",las=1)
ticks<-c(0,25,50,75)
axis(1,at=ticks,labels=c("","A1","A2","B1"))
```

[image]

Comment: problem is your `xlim` and `ylim`, which are too large

Comment: I cant change ylim because I need thin bars. Smaller limits will make them thicker.

Comment: you need to change `ylim` and the height of your image

Comment: Possibly relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32268654/remove-png-plot-margins ; also try searching `[r] plot margins`